# Extracting characters from a word image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on a project on Python where I need to break a word image into it's constituent letters. I am using OpenCV to threshold the image using Otsu's Binarization.
I have looked at libraries (like PyTesseract) but most of these just provide tools for OCR which output the text they read. 
However, I need a library that can segment a word into letters, not even to identify what the character is but just to do something like - say there is an image of a word saying "TEST", I want the library to break it down to four individual images containing the letters T, E, S and T. Is there anything that already exists to do this on Python? Does anything in OpenCV handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey do you got a solution for this. I am also looking for the same

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be possible with Tesseract (with PyTesseract, which you mentioned):

"With box coordinates than you can copy relevant part of image and create necessary array."

from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/v6bqJu8xyVI, with more or less the exact same question.